# 1 Solar panel to 2 mppt, to 2 separated batteries

Tags: batteries, solar-cell, mppt, lifepo4

In my motorhome I have 1 solar panel (500w) to a one victrom mppt 30A, to one battery 100A of lifePo4.

Now I need more battery because i have a new 12v fridge, so I bought other battery 230A lifepo4, and a booster, I don't like the idea of parallel batteries so i was thinking about.

My idea: 1 solar panel (500w) 2 lines to 2 differents mppts (30A-20A or 30-30) and each one to one batteries, without connection between batteries or mppts.

Also i will conect the big batterie to a booster to help it to charge faster.

What do you think about? it will work or there is any problem? My idea is that both mppts charge both batteries as much as they need in any situation, if both need to be charged both mppts take power, but when one battery is charged the other one takes all the power.

I don't know if i'm wrong or right.

Thank you.

Comment: Two MPPTs per panel is unpredictable, probably unstable.